How to integrate Articulate 360 course with .NET project and track completion status using SCORM?
I have created a course on Articulate 360 and downloaded the course zip folder. I also have another project built on .NET, and I would like to integrate the course into that project and track the status of its completion. I am using SCORM as the middleware, but I am unable to track the progress. How can I resolve this issue?
